# If a div missing then hide an other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a module in Joomla for news and takes articles dynamically.
Some time, articles aren't so many and it displays empty fields because it is set to grab 7 articles.

When an article is displayed it contains this code:

```
<div class="ns2-row">

  <div class="ns2-row-inner">

    <div class="ns2-column flt-left col-1">
          CONTENT
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

When there is no article this is the code:

```
<div class="ns2-row">

  <div class="ns2-row-inner">

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm thinking is:
if div.ns2-column missing from div.ns2-row-inner then hide div.ns2-row

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Shadow's help I found the solution. My problem was that I had one more jQuery library and I got some problems. So, I did that:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_8_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery_1_8_3('div.ns2-row-inner').filter(function(){
   return jQuery_1_8_3(this).find('div.ns2-column').length==0;
}).closest('div.ns2-row').hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : You can use `.filter()` and check if element has `ns2-column` to return TRUE or FALSE. For TRUE, use `closest('div.ns2-row')` to find parent `div` and then hide it.

```
$('div.ns2-row-inner').filter(function(){
   return $(this).find('div.ns2-column').length==0;
}).closest('div.ns2-row').hide();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bz694y19/1/)**

Comment: Could you modify that for jQuery 1.4.3? Because when I add this it works on this module but it affects bad another module which grab jQuery 1.4.3

Comment: It is bad idea to modify jQuery library. Check if other module refering to some other version of jQuery and use the same.

Comment: I didn't mean to modify the library. But the code that you made to reform for 1.4.3. However, I did .noConflict tactic. I added that here as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ns2-row').each(function()
{
    $(this).toggle($(this).find('.ns2-row-inner').has('.ns2-column'));
});
```

Explanation: since you said "7 articles" I've used `each` to iterate (I assume there is more than one row). Inside the each, it will toggle the visibility of `this` (`.ns2-row`) based on whether its `.ns2-row-inner` child element contains an `.ns2-column` element.

**Further reading on what I've used:**

Toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Has: http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ns2-row').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.ns2-row-inner .ns2-column').length === 0){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

**Reference:**

[length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

[each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: You're missing some `'` or `"` characters on your first line (in the selector).

Answer (score 0):

That script should be like this, I guess

```
$('.ns2-row').each(function()
{
  $(this).toggle($(this).find('ns2-row-inner .ns2-column').length > 0);
});
```

Comment: This will work, but (to be pedantic), the user asked that the `.ns2-column` element be checked in the context of `.ns2-row-inner`. It might be fine if it's anywhere else.

Comment: I assume `.ns2-row-inner` is just a wrapper. It will be there even if one content div is present

Comment: `if div.ns2-column missing from div.ns2-row-inner` < your code doesn't check for this.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. Our assumptions are different. The OP needs to post one more row to confirm our assumption

Comment: He doesn't. I'm not assuming anything. You're assuming he didn't mean it when he said `from div.ns2-row-inner`, I'm assuming I need to check whether it's missing `from div.ns2-row-inner` just as he said.